# JavaScript date regex for iOS

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios

I had a working regex for date until I tested it in the iOS simulator. Apparently, iOS requires a month name (ex: Jan), two digit date and four digit number.

I'm new to regular expressions but here was my attempt, it was unsuccessful.

```
/^(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\s\d{2},\d{4}$/;
```

Comment: What is the problem? How was your attempt unsuccessful?

Comment: I am in Mobile Application Development and I had to build a form that stores data in local storage. I had to have fields that were validated. The regex I had worked fine in other browsers, but when I tested it it in the iOS simulator, of course my error message popped up saying I had to enter a valid date and then because it wouldn't validate my date, it wouldn't store my data in local storage.

Answer (score 2):

Try this `/^\d{1,2}(\-|\/|\.)\d{1,2}\1\d{4}$/` for mm/dd/yyyy

and for dd/mmm/yyyy

`^(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-]))\/(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\/\d{4}$`

Comment: OP is asking for `mmm`, not `mm`

Comment: :) Close enough. `mmm dd yyyy` is probably what he/she is looking for.

Comment: so just a little tweak in the above regex..and he/she will get what is required..

Answer (score 1):

Your expression accepts strings like this:

```
jan 12,2012 // works
Jan 12,2012 // doesn't work!
```

Notice the capital J. Regular expressions are case sensitive, maybe that is why it doesn't work for you.

Try something like this:

```
/^((j|J)an|(f|F)eb|(m|M)ar|(a|A)pr|(m|M)ay|(j|J)un|(j|J)ul|(a|A)ug|(s|S)ep|(o|O)ct|(n|N)ov|(d|D)ec)\s\d{2},\d{4}$/
```

Do you have to define the months? If you have more flexibility try this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{3}\s\d{2},\d{4}$/
/[a-zA-Z]{3}\s\d{2},\d{4}/     // works also
```

Here is a good site, which i use for testing my regular expressions:
[RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/)

Greets

Comment: The `/i` switch can be used to make it case-insensitive as well.

Comment: @ Riplexus, thank you for responding to my post.  I tested both expressions. I thought for sure they would work, but unfortunately, it is still not accepting the data and entering it in my local storage. When I enter it in the iOS simulator, the simulator shows the entire date, but the output is a three string date name.  I don't know if that has anything to do with it not validating.  Thank you for the link to RegexPal. I've bookmarked it for future reference.  @Cthulhu, I'm very new at this. I'm not familiar with the /i switch. Thank you both for your responses.

Comment: I think we need some reference code to help you, the regex alone should work. Can you post us some code to give us better context?

Comment: //Date Validation
  var date =/^((j|J)an|(f|F)eb|(m|M)ar|(a|A)pr|(m|M)ay|(j|J)un|(j|J)ul|(a|A)ug|(s|S)ep|(o|O)ct|(n|N)ov|(d|D)ec)\s\d{2},\d{4}$/;
  if(!(date.exec(getCalDay.value))){
   var dateError = "Please enter a valid date in the following format: Jan/dd/yy";
   getCalDay.style.border = "1px solid red";
   messageAry.push(dateError);
  }

Comment: Are you writing javascript code for the iOS Browser?
Try identifying the current value of getCalDay for debugging purposes. Insert "alert(getCalDay.value);alert(typeof getCalDay.value);" in front of your posted code block and tell us what the output is please.

Comment: I am trying to make it cross-browser compatible, but mainly it has to be for the iOS browser. I am a mobile application development student and this is for my Visual Frameworks class.  Alert normally gives some sort of popup message. I inserted the alert code before my code block for my date variable and didn't get a popup at all.